# Custom DataGrid row selection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid control with 2 columns, one text, and one ToggleButton.
I need to be able to click on the ToggleButton cell, **without** the row be selected as a result of the click.
The ToggleButton is a show\hide property, and I don't want it to change the current selected item.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgMask"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Controlers.MasksInfo.AllMasks}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Controlers.MasksInfo.CurrentMask}"
          Margin="10"
          Height="283"
          CanUserAddRows="false"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Controlers.MasksInfo.SelectedMaskCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgMask, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ShowHide">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}"
                        Click="ShowHideFlip_Click"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that work by default because buttons handle the click event?

Comment: The row is getting selected AND the click handler is called afterward.

Comment: Is your problem that your whole row gets selected as a result of click ?

Comment: Yes. I don't want the row nor the cell to be selected when I click the ToggleButton. I only need it to be selected when I click the other cells (here its Text cell).

Comment: I would think you might be able to use the selectionchanged event to check the IsVisible property of the new selection and revert to old selection if set to false?

Comment: Could be, but this way my binded variable `SelectedItem="{Binding Controlers.MasksInfo.CurrentMask}">` will get the new value, and the old value, complicating the ViewModel logic, which need to ignore the first value set.